# A simple proof for Glasser: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-a/x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx, a>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-a/x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx~~~~(1)$$
Several difficult integral can be handled using (1) easily. For instance we know that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sech}^2 x~dx=2~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$ but what is interesting is that one may verify numerically that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{sech}^2(x-a/x)~dx=2, a>0.~~~~~~~~~(3)$$ This interesting property (1) follows from Glasser's Master Theorem. See one more interesting integral and its solutions in MSE post:s
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem.

In (1) what is also interesting is that LHS is independent of $a(>0)$. I have tried proving (1) or even (3) by the ordinary rules of integration ( Real Analysis) without a success. Can someone help me?

**EDIT:** One more friendly (doable by hand) twin is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\pi=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+(x-a/x)^2} dx , a >0$$

Comment: See [Glasser’s Master Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the integrand is even, we have
$$\mathcal{I} \stackrel{def}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{\cosh^2(x-\frac{a}{x})} dx
= 2\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\cosh^2(x-\frac{a}{x})}dx$$
In one copy of the integral on RHS, change variables to $y = \frac{a}{x}$, one get
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\cosh^2(x-\frac{a}{x})} =
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh^2(\frac{a}{y} - y)} \frac{a}{y^2}dy$$
Renaming $y$ back to $x$ and add back to another copy of integral on RHS, we get
$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x - \frac{a}{x})}\left(1 + \frac{a}{x^2}\right)dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x - \frac{a}{x})}\frac{d}{dx}\left(x - \frac{a}{x}\right) dx$$
Change variable to $z = x - \frac{a}{x}$, this becomes
$$\mathcal{I} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dz}{\cosh^2(z)}$$
i.e. transform your integral $(3)$ to integral $(2)$, the one you already know.

Let's look at the more general identity $(1)$.

As you increases $x$ from $-\infty$ to $0$, $x - \frac{a}{x}$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ once. If one further increases $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$, $x - \frac{a}{x}$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ the second time.
For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x_1(t) < 0$, $x_2(t) > 0$ be the two roots of
$$x - \frac{a}{x} = t \equiv x^2 - tx - a = 0$$
This is a quadratic equation in $x$. By Vieta's formula, we have

$$x_1(t) + x_2(t) = t \implies x_1'(t) + x_2'(t) = 1$$

If you change variable to $t = x - \frac{a}{x}$ for both $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$, we obtain:

$$\begin{align} 
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x - \frac{a}{x}) dx
&= \left(\int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^\infty\right) f(x - \frac{a}{x})dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) x'_1(t) dt +
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) x'_2(t) dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) (x'_1(t) + x'_2(t))dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)dt
\end{align}$$

This is the identity $(1)$ we seek.

Comment: +1 for solution but this integral is infinite  $O(x^{-2})$ near zero

Comment: @Empy2 oops, I will fix that.

Comment: @arcille hui Thanks for a great proof using the real analysis and make it attractive even at a pre-degree level.

Answer (score 5):

$u=x-\frac ax\Rightarrow du=(1+\frac a{x^2})dx$ and so:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-a/x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(u)}{1+\frac a{x^2}}dx$$
now we need to get this expression on the bottom in terms of $u$.
$$\frac{f(u)}{1+a/x^2}=\frac{x^2f(u)}{x^2+a}=f(u)-\frac{a^2}{x^2+a}f(u)$$
So now the challenge we face is showing that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a^2}{x^2+a}f(u)du=0$$
we can start by trying to undo the substitution:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a}{x^2+a}f(x-a/x)(1+a/x^2)dx=a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1+a/x^2}{x^2+a}f(x-a/x)dx$$
$$=a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x^2}\frac{x^2+a}{x^2+a}f(x-a/x)dx=a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x-a/x)}{x^2}dx$$
if we try letting $x\to-x$ and combine we get:
$$I_1=\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(-x+a/x)+f(x-a/x)}{x^2}dx=\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(-(x-a/x))+f(x-a/x)}{x^2}dx$$
now we can try and make our substitution again:
$$u=x-a/x$$
$$I_1=\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(u)+f(-u)}{x^2}\frac{du}{1+a/x^2}dx=\frac a2\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(u)+f(-u)}{x^2+a}du$$
Now notice how this function is symmetric i.e. $I_1=-I_1\therefore I_1=0$

Comment: A very nice work of your.

Comment: @ZAhmed thank you, hope it helped :)

Comment: I don't get it. The first substitution $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-a/x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(u)}{1+\frac a{x^2}}du$$ already is kinda off. The $x$ in the denominator depends on the domain of $x$. If $u$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, one $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $0$ and the other $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$. They are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-\frac ax ) \ dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} 
\overset{x=-\sqrt a e^{-t}} {f(x-\frac ax )\ dx }+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \overset{x=\sqrt a e^t}{f(x-\frac ax ) \ dx}\\
= &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underset{ x=\sqrt a (e^t-e^{-t})}{f[\sqrt a(e^t-e^{-t})]\sqrt a(e^t +e^{-t})} dt =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx
\end{align}

Comment: Very cute indeed, a pre-degree student will love it

Comment: Very good consise method

Answer (score 3):

Glasser's formula (1) amounts to the statement that the image measure $\mu$ of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\Bbb R$, under the (two-to-one) transformation $\varphi: x\mapsto x-a/x$ is also Lebesgue measure. To verify this it suffices to show that $\mu\{(A,B]\}=B-A$ for each $A<B$. Notice that if we define $\alpha_\pm:={A\pm\sqrt{A^2+4}\over 2}$ and $\beta_\pm:={B\pm\sqrt{B^2+4}\over 2}$ (so that $\varphi(\alpha_\pm) = A$ and $\varphi(\beta_\pm)=B)$ then
$$
\eqalign{
\mu\{(A,B]\}
&=\lambda\{\varphi^{-1}\{(A,B]\}\}=\lambda\{(\alpha_-,\beta_-]\}+\lambda\{(\alpha_+,\beta_+]\}\cr
&=(\beta_--\alpha_-)+(\beta_+-\alpha_+)\cr
&=B-A,\cr
}
$$
because $\beta_++\beta_-=B$ and $\alpha_++\alpha_-=A$.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually also not difficult to prove the general case.

Let $$u=x-a-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n}{x-b_n} \tag{1}$$
where $a,a_n,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_n\geq 0$. This function obviously has poles at the $b_n$'s. Let's assume the $b_n$ are in order $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_N$. Then when $x$ increases from $-\infty$ to $b_1$, $u$ increases from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Similarly, for $x\in(b_k,b_{k+1})$, $u$ increases from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Finally, for $x>b_N$, $u$ increases from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Equation (1) also defines a polynomial of degree N+1 with N+1 solutions $x_k(u)$ (for $k=0,1,2,...,N$) and each solution corresponds to one of the N+1 domains separated by the $N$ poles, i.e. when $u$ increases over the domain $(-\infty,\infty)$, $x_k(u)$ is increasing on $(b_k,b_{k+1})$ (with $b_0=-\infty$ and $b_{N+1}=+\infty$).

Now, rewriting (1) as a polynomial, we have
$$0=(x-a-u)\prod_{n=1}^N (x-b_n) - \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\neq n}}^N (x-b_k) = x^{N+1}-(u+a+b_1+...+b_N) x^N+O(x^{N-1}) \\
=(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_N) = x^{N+1} - (x_0+x_1+...+x_N)x^N + O(x^{N-1}) \, .$$
By comparing the coefficient of $x^N$, we see that $$x_0+x_1+...+x_N=u+a+b_1+...+b_N \, . \tag{2}$$

Back to our integral, it can now be written as follows
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, {\rm d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{b_1} f(u) \, {\rm d}x + \int_{b_1}^{b_2} f(u) \, {\rm d}x + \dots + \int_{b_N}^{\infty} f(u) \, {\rm d}x \\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, \frac{{\rm d}x_0}{{\rm d}u} \, {\rm d}u + \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, \frac{{\rm d}x_1}{{\rm d}u} \, {\rm d}u + \dots + \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, \frac{{\rm d}x_N}{{\rm d}u} \, {\rm d}u \\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, {\rm d}u \, \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}u}(x_0+x_1+\dots+x_N)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u) \, {\rm d}u$$
by Equation (2).