# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(T(x))\,\frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\,\frac{dx}{\pi(1+y^2)}$ when $T(x)=\frac{x^2 -1}{2x}$ and $T(0)=0$

Tags: analysis, ergodic-theory

> Let $T:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be given by
> $$T(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x- \frac1x \right)$$
> for $x\ne 0$, and $T(0) = 0$. The substitution $y = T(x)$ establishes the following integral equality for any $f\in L^1$:
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+y^2)} $$

---

First of all, $T(0^+) = T(-\infty) = -\infty$, and $T(0^-) = T(\infty) = \infty$. Also, on solving $2y = x - \frac1x$ for $x$, we get $x = y\pm \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$. Since $T$ is injective when restricted to $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$, we split the integral into two parts;
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} + \int_0^\infty f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)}$$
Putting $y = T(x)$, we get
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\, \frac{(2y^2 + 2y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + 1)\, dy}{(y^2 \pm y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + 1)^2}}_{I_1}$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\, \frac{(2y^2 + 2y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + 1)\, dy}{(y^2 \pm y\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + 1)^2}}_{I_2}$$
Finally,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(T(x))\, \frac{dx}{\pi(1+x^2)} = I_1 + I_2$$
but I am hesitant to add the two integrals up since it's not clear to me which branch of $x$ (in terms of $y$) to pick, i.e., $x = y + \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$ or $x = y - \sqrt{y^2 + 1}$? How should I go about this?

---

**Reference:** Pg. $19$, Section $2.1$, *Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* by Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward.

Comment: $T(0)=\pm\infty\neq0$

Comment: @Svyatoslav What? I have defined $T(0) = 0$.

Comment: If you define $T(0)=0,\,T(x)$ is not continuous. $x-\frac{1}{x}\to -\frac{1}{x}\to\pm\infty$ at $x\to 0$

Comment: $T$ doesn't have to be continuous. By the way, $T$ is continuous *almost everywhere.* @Svyatoslav

Comment: Prove that $T$ is $\mu$ invariant ($\mu(dx)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the restrictions of $T$  to $(-\infty,0)$ and $T$ to $(0,\infty)$, denoted by $T_-$ and $T_+$ respectively,  are strictly monotone increasing functions onto $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover
\begin{align}
T^{-1}_+(y)&=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}>0\\
T^{-1}_-(y)&=y-\sqrt{y^2+1}<0
\end{align}
This shows which branches to use in the OP

---

Perhaps a simpler method to prove the main statement in the OP is to show that the map $T$ is invariant with respect the probability measure $\mu(dx)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx$ (the standard Cauchy measure on $\mathbb{R}$),  that is $\mu(T^{-1}(A)=\mu(A)$ for all $A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for then,
$$\int f\circ T\,d\mu=\int f\,d(\mu\circ T^{-1})=\int f\,d\mu$$
Since the cumulative distributions fully characterize probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, it suffices to show that $\mu\big(T^{-1}((-\infty,a])\big)=\mu((-\infty,a])$ with $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Given $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let
\begin{align}
\alpha_+=a+\sqrt{a^2+1}\qquad \alpha_-=a-\sqrt{a^2+1}
\end{align}
$\alpha_-<0< \alpha_+$ are the roots of the equation
$T(x)=a$, $x\neq0$. Notice that $T^{-1}((-\infty,a])=(-\infty,\alpha_-]\cup(0,\alpha_+]$; whence

\begin{align}
\mu((-\infty,\alpha_-])&=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\alpha_-)+\frac12\\
\mu((0,\alpha_+])&=\frac1{\pi}\arctan(\alpha_+)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mu(T^{-1}(-\infty,a])&=\frac1{\pi}\big(\arctan(a+\sqrt{a^2+1})+\arctan(a-\sqrt{a^2+1})\big)+\frac12\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(a) +\frac12=\mu((-\infty,a])
\end{align}

That latter identity follows from
$$\tan(\theta+\psi)=\frac{\tan(\theta)+\tan(\psi)}{1-\tan(\theta)\tan(\psi)}$$

---

The paper Letac, G., *Which Functions Preserve Cauchy Laws?*,
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society,
Vol. 67, No. 2 (Dec., 1977), pp. 277-286, contains a more detailed study of invariant measures of the Cauchy distribution,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is necessary to go through the said change of variables, since the author establishes this integral inequality to prove that $T$ is measure-preserving.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic: It is not  necessary to go through all changes of variable that you laid down. Notice that two probability measures are the same iff they have the same distribution function and so, if $(\mu\circ T^{-1})((-\infty,a])=\mu(-\infty,a])$ for all $a$, then $\mu\circ T^{-1}=\mu$. This turns out to be easy using a simple trigonometric identity as I did). Of course you can always use a more seemingly *general* approach and instead of considering $\mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,a]}$ you consider a general nonnegative (or bounded) measurable function $f$.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic:  in which case, the key (as I also pointed out) is to notice that the restriction $T_-$ of  $T$ to $(−\infty,0)$ and the restriction $T_+$ of $T$ to $(0,\infty)$ are strictly monotone increasing functions onto $\mathbb{R}$, and precede with the change of variables as you did in your posting. I added in my posting the inverses of $T_-$ and $T_+$ which addresses your question about the branches. I still prefer the simpler method of distributions  I presented. with respect Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic: this *simpler* technique also yields a simple proof of  the [Glasser master's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3946769/121671) formula for integrals which has been discussed many times in MSE.

Comment: How do we know which branch to use and when? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: for $T_-$ you want to ue the negative branch of course, $y\mapstp y-\sqrt{y^2+1}<0$ and for $T_+$ you want to use the positive branch $y\mapsto y+\sqrt{y^2+1}>0$